# RStudio - Which edition/release am I running

Tags: r, rstudio

Is there a command (such as 'RStudio.Version()') or method for identifying whether it's open source/community or commercial?

Not my intention to ask such an ostensibly obvious question, however I've searched valiantly on the Web and it's becoming a frustration.

Thanks in advance if you can demystify.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to find what you need in `rstudioapi::getVersion` and/or `rstudioapi::versionInfo`.

Comment: No, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

With RStudio v1.2 (not yet released), professional builds of RStudio will come with the `edition` field set in `RStudio.Version()`, e.g.

```
> RStudio.Version()
$citation

To cite RStudio in publications use:

  RStudio Team (2018). RStudio: Integrated Development for R. RStudio, Inc., Boston, MA URL
  http://www.rstudio.com/.

A BibTeX entry for LaTeX users is

  @Manual{,
    title = {RStudio: Integrated Development Environment for R},
    author = {{RStudio Team}},
    organization = {RStudio, Inc.},
    address = {Boston, MA},
    year = {2018},
    url = {http://www.rstudio.com/},
  }


$mode
[1] "desktop"

$edition
[1] "Professional"

$version
[1] '1.2.853.2'
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  Does this mean there's no present way of being able to ascertain edition?  I find this lack of a clear method surprising.

Comment: No, this doesn't require RStudio 1.2. RStudio 1.0 has the same behavior. `$edition` will be `NULL` if you're open source, and `Professional` for the commercial edition.

Comment: Neither are apparent.  Excuse the non-formatting of this: > RStudio.Version()
$`citation`

To cite RStudio in publications use:

  RStudio Team (2016). RStudio: Integrated Development for R. RStudio, Inc., Boston, MA URL http://www.rstudio.com/.

A BibTeX entry for LaTeX users is

  @Manual{,
    title = {RStudio: Integrated Development Environment for R},
    author = {{RStudio Team}},
    organization = {RStudio, Inc.},
    address = {Boston, MA},
    year = {2016},
    url = {http://www.rstudio.com/},
  }


$`mode`
[1] "desktop"

$version
[1] ‘1.1.453’